# Is Swiss cheese homeomorphic to a ball?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In topology, I understand how most solids are homeomorphic to $n$-holed donuts, but I've never seen anyone mention internal holes (or should I say "bubbles", because holes are something else).

If you take a block of Swiss cheese, how can you get rid of the bubbles inside without cutting or gluing parts that were not close to each other?

I've never heard anyone talk about it so I assume it's not a problem but I don't understand how you can remove internal holes without breaking the rules of topology.

Comment: You're asking how to cut Swiss cheese without cutting it? I'm not sure it can be done.

Comment: You   can, with Gruyere cheese –it has no bubbles… :-)

Comment: You may be thinking of the assertion that *surfaces* (2-manifolds) are homeomorphic to $n$-holed tori.  *Solids* can be much more complex.  A Swiss cheese is definitely not homeomorphic, nor even homotopic, to a sphere or a ball (be sure to keep the distinction clear!).

Comment: @NateEldredge Wait, so when people say two shapes are homeomorphic (like a donut and a mug), they're talking only about the surfaces? So we're always dealing with empty shapes?

Comment: Well, it's true that the surface of a mug is homeomorphic to a torus, and a solid mug is homeomorphic to a solid torus.  But you want to be careful which statement you mean.  You can't always go back and forth - not all surfaces are the boundary of a solid.

Comment: @NateEldredge Ok then. Well my question is specifically about that. Is a ball with $n$ "bubbles" inside it homeomorphic to a ball with none? And to a ball with $n+1$ bubbles?

Comment: Ok.  The short answer is that they are not homeomorphic, but rigorously proving it takes some work.

Comment: Suppose there are $n$ bubbles, then we can always deformation retracted the cheese to $n$ spheres such that any two adjacent spheres have at least one point in comon, so that it forms a chain of spheres. Thus cannot homeomorphic with a ball. @TeleportingGoat

Answer (score 2):

To give a more explicit view and for the sake of reducing the number of unanswered questions.

Assume that there $n$ "bubbles" i.e. removed $n$ balls from the whole space. Then you can always arrange them in a line without breaking the rule of topology. Note that **I'm talking about the solid shape instead of just the surface.**

Let $X$ denotes the resulting space (swiss cheese). We can regard this as many $K=D^2\setminus B(x_0,r=1/2)$ joining together, where $D^2$ and $B$ centered at the same point, since the **outer** boundary of $X$ is homeomorphic with $ \partial D^2$. So, $$X\cong\bigsqcup_{i=1}^n K_i/\sim$$

where $\sim$ is generated by $x_i\sim x_j$ iff $x_i,x_j$ belongs to the outer boundary of $K_i,K_j$ respectively, and $j=i+1$, for each $K$ there is only one point that can be identified.

For each point $x_j\in K_j$, we have a vector between $x$ and its final position (those vectors intersect at the center), so then define a family of maps $f_{i,t}:K_i\to \partial D^2$ by
$$f_{i,t}(x)=t\dfrac{x}{||x||}+(1-t)x$$
(We're sliding each point through a vector from the center and map it to the boundary, and this is well-defined and continuous, you can try to prove it，note that the center can be regarded as the orgin of $K_i$)

and the inverse which is an natural inclusion map $g_i:\partial D^2\to K_i$.

So $X\simeq \bigsqcup S^2_i/\sim$ (i.e. **is homotopy equivalent** to $n$ spheres joining together) It is **not** homeomorphic with a Torus because $X$ is simply connected but a torus isn't. And it is **not** homeomorphic with a ball, because a solid ball doesn't have any bubble in it. Hope this will help.